# <g:countrySelect> Tag: How to set values as country names instead of country codes

Tags: grails

On my view, instead of using a normal `<g:textField>` field in the form, I would like to make use of Grails' `<g:countrySelect>` widget.

### My problem

```
<g:countrySelect name="country" value="${myObjInstance?.country}"/>
```

...produces...

```
<select name="country" id="country">
   <option value="afg">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="alb">Albania</option>
   ...
</select>
```

This would mean that, when the form is submitted, it will assign the value as country code (e.g. "afg") instead of the country name ("Afghanistan"). I prefer using the full country name as value. If possible, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the taglib as is gives you that ability.  You would either need to extend it or use your own Country collection + <g:select />

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using a normal <g:textField> with jQuery auto-completion. It seems to work pretty well, and the advantage of this is that it only loads what the user's looking for (AJAX request after say 2 chars typed) instead of pre-loading a long list of countries - speeding up the user experience. Obviously with the countries bootstrapped into a table. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use this [enum of the ISO_3166 country code](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/CountryCode)s to get the full length description. Eg:

```
CountryCode.getByCode(params.country).getName()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using a normal <g:textField> with jQuery auto-completion. It seems to work pretty well, and the advantage of this is that it only loads what the user's looking for (AJAX request after say 2 chars typed) instead of pre-loading a long list of countries - speeding up the user experience. Obviously with the countries bootstrapped into a table. :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question...

The values can stay as is (country codes) and then just use country codes. On your views, you can make use of the grails `country()` method to display the country name, e.g.

Let's say the country code is "afg" (the value saved in your table). On your view (GSP) you can use

```
<div>${country(code: fieldValue(bean: myObjInstance, field: "country"))}</div>
```

This will print out

```
<div>Afghanistan</div>
```

---

Instead of

```
<div>${fieldValue(bean: myObjInstance, field: "country")}</div>
```

...that was used before:

```
<div>afg</div>
```